# D parallel loop

Tags: d, phobos

First, how D create parallel foreach (underlying logic)?

```
int main(string[] args)
{
    int[] arr;
    arr.length = 100000000;
    /* Why it is working?, it's simple foreach which working with
       reference to int from arr, parallel function return ParallelForeach!R
       (ParallelForeach!int[]), but I don't know what it is.
       Parallel function is part od phobos library, not D builtin function, then what
       kind of magic is used for this? */
    foreach (ref e;parallel(arr))
    {
        e = 100;
    }
    foreach (ref e;parallel(arr))
    {
        e *= e;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And second, why it is slower then simple foreach? 
Finally, If I create my own taskPool (and don't use global taskPool object), program never end. Why?

Answer (score 5):

parallel returns a struct (of type `ParallelForeach`) that implements the `opApply(int delegate(...))` foreach overload.

when called the struct submits a parallel function to the private `submitAndExecute` which submits the same task to all threads in the pool.

this then does:

```
scope(failure)
{
    // If an exception is thrown, all threads should bail.
    atomicStore(shouldContinue, false);
}

while (atomicLoad(shouldContinue))
{
    immutable myUnitIndex = atomicOp!"+="(workUnitIndex, 1);
    immutable start = workUnitSize * myUnitIndex;
    if(start >= len)
    {
        atomicStore(shouldContinue, false);
        break;
    }

    immutable end = min(len, start + workUnitSize);

    foreach(i; start..end)
    {
        static if(withIndex)
        {
            if(dg(i, range[i])) foreachErr();
        }
        else
        {
            if(dg(range[i])) foreachErr();
        }
    }
}
```

where `workUnitIndex` and `shouldContinue` are shared variables and `dg` is the foreach delegate

The reason it is slower is simply because of the overhead required to pass the function to the threads in the pool and atomically accessing the shared variables.

the reason your custom pool doesn't shut down is likely you don't shut down the threadpool with [`finish`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_parallelism.html#.TaskPool.finish)

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. I have one another question. How I can use (overload it in my class) opApply? In documentaion isn't described oppApply operator overloading.

Comment: See http://dlang.org/statement.html#ForeachStatement and http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/foreach_opapply.html